# remover arquivo javascript do header de uma página

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

Tenho um aplicativo asp.net onde carrego, de acordo com a vontade do usuário diversos usercontrols.

Cada usercontrol carregado, via scriptmanagerproxy carrega um arquivo javascript. Como ele é carregado pelo usercontrol, ele vai parar no Header da página. O problema é que como eles não são removidos junto com o usercontrol, ao longo do tempo vão acumulando.

Como posso fazer para remover estas referencias aos arquivos javascripts não mais necessários?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar no seu script aqueles que são importantes e sobrescrever o head da página colocando estes importantes e apagando os não necessários, exemplo:

```
var scriptsNecessarios = [];
scriptsNecessarios[0] = "<script src=\"jquery-1.8.0.min.js\"></script>";
scriptsNecessarios[1] = "<script src=\"bootstrap.min.js\"></script>";
var head = scriptsNecessarios.toString();
head = scriptsNecessarios.replaceAll(',',' <br/> ');
document.head.innerHTML = head;
```